# Significant difference help

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have a quick question regarding which statistical test to use to test for a significant difference.

My set of data shows the monthly output of a product for the years between 2013-2017. A new system was put in place in mid-2017 to make the output process more efficient which has led to increased output.

I have calculated the mean output level (units) for each month 2013-2016 and want to compare this to the actual output in 2017.

Which statistical test can I use to show a significant difference for output in the months of June, July, Aug and Sept 2017 which have a higher output level compared to the 2013-2016 average?

[image]

[image]

Kind regards,

Harvey

Comment: Are  you really interested in just testing for a statistically significant difference or a meaningful difference?  Would it really be helpful if you found a 0.00001 difference and that was statistically significant?

Comment: Hi there, 
Thanks for the reply. I was hoping to find a significant difference (p<0.05). I was thinking perhaps a T-Test or an ANOVA test ?

Comment: Was the supposedly superior new process in place only during May-Aug? Or did it continue from May through the end of the year. // It seems you should make the comparison only for months in which the process was different.

Comment: Hi there, the process was introduced in May and continued after that. The process aimed to alleviate a backlog of output orders hence the spike. Which statistical test could I use to easily show a sig. difference?

Comment: Comment continued: With data ` old = c(20.25, 20.5, 24.25, 33.75);  new = c(87, 48, 52, 44)` a one-sided paired t test in R using ` t.test(old, new, pair=T, alte="less")` returns P-value 3.5%. A one-sample Wilcoxon test on the four differences cannot show a P-value smaller than 5% because there aren't enough pairs.

Comment: Then why did you (misleadingly) highlight only four months? If you compare old-vs-new for 7 months May-Dec, then you have new better than old for all 7 pairs. The 1-samp Wilcoxon test shows a significant increase.

Comment: Hard to see how you could get a simpler test than noting 7 increases out of 7 is significant with P-value $(.5)^7.$

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. I have little to none experience with advanced stats, what would be the simplest way of completing a The 1-samp Wilcoxon test ? Thanks again

Comment: OK, I'll show you. But my idea is that you need not permanently remain 'inexperienced': R code: `wilcox.test(old, new, pair=T, alt="less")`, where each vector `new` and `old` contains May thru Dec observations to get P-value 0.007813. // Perhaps google 'Wilcoxon paired test in R' for one of several help pages.